# Wordpress 3.0 MultiBlog Theming

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was wondering if Wordpress 3.0 will allow me separate instances of the same theme to customize to my liking? Then I could use these two themes in two separate blogs in that same multiuser Wordpress 3.0 instance? Is this possible?

Like could I completely customize the TwentyTen theme and then install another TwentyTen theme under a different name/folder and lcustomize that as well.

I am trying to learn the ins-and-outs of Wordpress 3.0 for use in a bunch of different projects including internal employee blogs.

Any insight would be great on how I would accomplish something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just create a new copy of the TwentyTen theme folder with a different name inside the /wp-content/themes directory:

```
/wp-content
    /themes
        /TwentyTen
        /TwentyTenWithFancyMods
```

Then open up the **styles.css** file inside the new theme's folder and edit the comment at the top (and even create a new screenshot.png if you want).  That way, when you're in the WordPress theme control panel, you'll be able to tell the two themes apart.

Comment: i agree. you should also change the original screenshot.png in your theme. so you can easily spot them in theme dashboard